# groupby in pandas with where clause to get count

Tags: python, date, pandas-groupby

I have data table with date field, created(user_accout) and user_id.

| date | created | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-05-07 | user1. |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | use2. |
| 2022-01-03 | 2021-02-02 | use3. |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-05 | use4. |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 | use5. |
| 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-08 | use6. |

I want to get a count (as new users based on the created field)of new users grouped by the date field

| date | created | customer_id | new_users(based on date'colum1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2021-05-07 | user1. | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | use2. | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2021-02-02 | use3. | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-05 | use4. | 0 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 | use5. | 2 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-08 | use6. | 0 |

i tried using the groupby but i could not able to assign date == created to get count of the new users on particular date field.

Comment: I don't understand how the values in your new column are determined. Can you explain, please, why for example you have number 1 in the new column in the fourth row of new table?

Comment: Thanks @IlyaV.Schurov 
 True, That column is 0. actually, for every user there is created_date, the new column Is to get new users on the current date( date field)

Comment: Is it true that for each date in the first column you just want to count how many times this date occurrs in the second column? Do you use `customer_id` column in any way?

Comment: customer_id is to count the distinct customers to get new customers based on created_date

Comment: You have number 2 in `new_users` in a row that corresponds to date 2022-01-05. Value 2022-01-05 is mentioned twice in the column `created`, but `customer_id` in both cases is the same (`use4.`). So according to `customer_id`, they are not distinct, it's the same customer. Why do you have number 2?

Comment: true, it was a mistype, the 'customer_id' are different

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it is better to split your data into two different tables. In the first table, you have only `creation_date`s and `customer_id`s. This is your actual input. It looks like this:

```
created_table = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        created=pd.Series(
            [
                "2022-01-07",
                "2022-01-02",
                "2022-01-05",
                "2022-01-02",
                "2022-01-05",
                "2022-01-05",
            ],
            dtype='datetime64[ns]'
        ),
        customer_id = ['user1', 'user2', 'user5', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6']
    )
)

    created     customer_id
0   2022-01-07  user1
1   2022-01-02  user2
2   2022-01-05  user5
3   2022-01-02  user4
4   2022-01-05  user5
5   2022-01-05  user6
```

I changed it a little bit to make it more illustrative.

Now as far as I understood, you want to count how many unique `customer_id`s exist for each date. This can be done with `groupby` and `nunique`.

```
customers_created = created_table.groupby('created')['customer_id'].nunique()

created     customer_id
2022-01-02  2
2022-01-05  2
2022-01-07  1
```

Now you probably want to join this results with a series of consecutive dates. First, let's create an index with such dates:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="2022-01-01", end="2022-01-10", name="date")
```

Now let's reindex our series `customers_created` with this new index:

```
(
    customers_created.reindex(dates, fill_value=0)
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"customer_id": "new_users"})
)

    date        new_users
0   2022-01-01  0
1   2022-01-02  2
2   2022-01-03  0
3   2022-01-04  0
4   2022-01-05  2
5   2022-01-06  0
6   2022-01-07  1
7   2022-01-08  0
8   2022-01-09  0
9   2022-01-10  0
```

Depending on what you need, series or dataframe, you may drop the last part (i.e. `.to_frame()`, etc).

This is probably what you were looking for. In your question, this table was merged with the original table, but I don't think it makes much sense, as there are no relation between rows of the initial table and the new table.

It is also possible that all values in `customer_id` are guaranteed to be unique. Then you can replace `created_table.groupby('created')['customer_id'].nunique()` with `created_table['created'].value_counts()`.